# Camera.getParameters() return null on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-camera

Here is my surface-changed event handling code:

```
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                parameters);
       //...
    }


    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                       Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        // it fails with NullPointerExceptiopn here,
        // when accessing "getSupportedPreviewSizes" method:
        // that means "parameters" is null
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            ///...
        }
    }
```

I initialize camera like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        camera = Camera.open();
    }
```

This problem doesn't occur on my Galaxy S Plus neither it happen on LG Optimus Black phone. Has anyone thoughts what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this.

```
parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()
```

Returns NULL on Galaxy Tab. So I just make a check if it is null and don't set new preview size in such case.  To this conclusion I've came after looking into standard Camera application sources.

Comment: Is parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() always returns null on Galaxy Tab? Also how do you set initial preview size if parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() returns null?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the camera variable was never initialized so you are calling getParameters() on null.   Try calling `camera = Camera.open();` first

Comment: Thanks, most likely you're right. Will try to find the best place to initialize the camera.

Comment: But... If camera isn't initialized I would probably get NPE on line "Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();". So looks like it is initialized at that moment.

Comment: When you run through the debugger with a break on that line, check the camera object to see if it is null.

Answer (score -1):

camera initialization depends a lot on the specific device. For instance a specific Samsung device GT5500 is reporting null (width = 0, height = 0) as a valid resolution for preview, but crashes the whole phone ("hard" reboot) if you try to use it. We experienced it with mixare augmented reality engine (http://www.mixare.org) and it was PITA to debug (since we didn't have the phone and could not reproduce the bug on any other hardware).

However, about getting the "right" preview size you can take a look at our code (it's a free and open source app) on github. In the file: https://github.com/mixare/mixare/blob/master/src/org/mixare/MixView.java (row 871 and onwards)

```
        List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = null;
        //On older devices (<1.6) the following will fail
        //the camera will work nevertheless
        supportedSizes = Compatibility.getSupportedPreviewSizes(parameters);

        //preview form factor
        float ff = (float)w/h;
        Log.d("Mixare", "Screen res: w:"+ w + " h:" + h + " aspect ratio:" + ff);

        //holder for the best form factor and size
        float bff = 0;
        int bestw = 0;
        int besth = 0;
        Iterator<Camera.Size> itr = supportedSizes.iterator();

        //we look for the best preview size, it has to be the closest to the
        //screen form factor, and be less wide than the screen itself
        //the latter requirement is because the HTC Hero with update 2.1 will
        //report camera preview sizes larger than the screen, and it will fail
        //to initialize the camera
        //other devices could work with previews larger than the screen though
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Camera.Size element = itr.next();
            //current form factor
            float cff = (float)element.width/element.height;
            //check if the current element is a candidate to replace the best match so far
            //current form factor should be closer to the bff
            //preview width should be less than screen width
            //preview width should be more than current bestw
            //this combination will ensure that the highest resolution will win
            Log.d("Mixare", "Candidate camera element: w:"+ element.width + " h:" + element.height + " aspect ratio:" + cff);
            if ((ff-cff <= ff-bff) && (element.width <= w) && (element.width >= bestw)) {
                bff=cff;
                bestw = element.width;
                besth = element.height;
            }
        } 
        Log.d("Mixare", "Chosen camera element: w:"+ bestw + " h:" + besth + " aspect ratio:" + bff);
        //Some Samsung phones will end up with bestw and besth = 0 because their minimum preview size is bigger then the screen size.
        //In this case, we use the default values: 480x320
        if ((bestw == 0) || (besth == 0)){
            Log.d("Mixare", "Using default camera parameters!");
            bestw = 480;
            besth = 320;
        }
        parameters.setPreviewSize(bestw, besth);
```

As you see we're not using directly the call to getSupportedPreviewSizes of the Camera class, but instead added a compatibility layer (the code is  here: https://github.com/mixare/mixare/blob/master/src/org/mixare/Compatibility.java ) because we needed compatibility with older phones. If you don't want to support older android releases you can use the method of the Camera class directly.

HTH
Daniele

Comment: You are using reflection and you are ignoring the case where Compatibility.getSupportedPreviewSizes(parameters) returns null. So whats the point?